# Laravel5.2 and Bootstrap form with method="post" doesn't work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5

I have bootstrap form when I make method="get" or I ignore method it work with get method,But When I make method="post"  this error appear.

```
The localhost page isn’t working
localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
```

This is the form

```
 <form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form row" name="contact-form" action="{{url('send-contact-us')}}" method="post">

                        <div class="form-group col-md-6"> 
                            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                            <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Subject">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                            <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Your Message Here"></textarea>
                        </div>                        
                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="Submit">
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

This is routes

```
Route::get('/send-contact-us','Front@send_contact_us');
```

This is send_contact_us function

```
public function send_contact_us()
    {

         if (Request::isMethod('POST'))
        {
        $data = array(
            'name' => Request::get('name'),'email'=>Request::get('email'),'subject'=> Request::get('subject'));
        $client_m=Request::get('message');
        $data_message=array('message_c'=>$client_m);


         //echo "we above MAIL";
        Mail::send('emails.message',$data_message, function ($message)use ($data) {
            $message->from($data['email'], 'E-SHOPPER');

            $message->to("azharnabil013@yahoo.com")->subject($data['subject']);

        });
        //echo"after mailsend count".count(Mail::failures());

        return view('contact_us', array('title' => 'Welcome', 'description' => '', 'page' => 'contact_us','subscribe'=>'','sent'=>"Message has been sent successfuly"));
    }
    }
```

Please,anyone help me to correct this error

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're route says Route::get. change it to Route::post.

Comment: I changed it But the same problem

Answer (score 0):

To handle the post request you will need to add a Route::post(); in your routes file.

```
Route::post($uri, $callback);
```

In your case, you can just replace the `Route::get` with `Route::post`.

```
Route::post('/send-contact-us','Front@send_contact_us');
```

For more information, you can refer the following link.
[Laravel HTTP Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing)

Comment: @Azhar Nabil Could you check if the action method of your form is pointing towards the respective address ?

Comment: I changed the route to post but the same problem .When I change the method="get " it works. so it point toward the respective address

Comment: Is it probability the problem with bootsrtap form?

Comment: I don't think so. Just inspect your form element in browser and check if method or action attribute of your form is changing. If not, then its probably not the frontend(bootstrap) problem. I have been working on laravel and bootstrap since few months but never experienced anything like this :-(

Comment: Did you make any changes in laravel configuration ?

Comment: I was use phpstorm and did this project on it.I am now use netbeans when i open this project with netbeans I found some error in js file as example but project work normally.I don''t change laravel configration

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117081/discussion-between-jaysingkar-and-azhar-nabil).